# Save to PG database in RoR only the value of a JSON curl request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, curl

I use the following code for processing JSON in my RoR API:

```
@message = Message.new
@message.text =  params.permit(:message)
@message.save
```

But it is saved in my postgresql database as

```
{"message"=>"the value of the message"}
```

How do I save only the value of the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`params.permit(:message)` will return a special parameters hash with everything but the `:message` key-value pair filtered out.  To get the value of the `:message` key, you need to use the `[]` operator.  Try this:

```
@message = Message.new
@message.text =  params.permit(:message)[:message]
@message.save
```